# IntelliJ Error Stripe - Turn off unit test errors

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've tried going through IntelliJ's thousands of inspections but can't find one for java unit test errors. Normally you get a light bulb next to the error/warning/suggestion which gives an option to disable the inspection but not for unit test errors.

I just want the error stripe showing red marks for java compile errors, not for unit test failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to disable the "JVM languages | Test frameworks | Failed line in test" inspection.